# How to download multiple files at same ajax call success using click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my file i have 2 anchor tags having their href. I am hitting both anchor tag at **ajax call success**.

```
<a id="exportExcelFatturaIcon" href ="${createLink(action: 'downloadExcel', params: [fileName:excelFileName])}" hidden>click here</a>
<a id="exportCsvFatturaIcon" href ="${createLink(action: 'downloadCSV', params: [fileName:csvFileName])}"  hidden>click here</a>
```

**Ajax Call:**

```
$("#exportFatturaButton").click(function(){
    var startDate = $("#startDateFattura").val();
    var endDate =  $("#endDateFattura").val();
    $("#loaderModal").modal('show');
    $.ajax({
        url: "${createLink(controller: 'ExportData',action: 'getDataBySearch')}",
        data: {
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate:endDate
        },
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#loaderModal").modal('hide');
                document.getElementById("exportExcelFatturaIcon").click();
                document.getElementById("exportCsvFatturaIcon").click();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            $("#loaderModal").modal('hide');
        }, complete: function (xhr, status) {
            $("#loaderModal").modal('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

**Problem Cases**

**Case 1:** 
When i hit only `document.getElementById("exportExcelFatturaIcon").click();` then only `excel` file will be download.

**Case 2:** 
When i hit only `document.getElementById("exportCsvFatturaIcon").click();` then only `csv` file will be download.

**Case 3:**
When i hit both 
`document.getElementById("exportExcelFatturaIcon").click();` 
`document.getElementById("exportCsvFatturaIcon").click();` then only `csv` file will be download not excel file.

**Requirement**

But in this case 3 i want both files should be download at same time not only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of triggering click event in success callback, try

```
window.open(document.getElementById("exportExcelFatturaIcon").href);
window.open(document.getElementById("exportCsvFatturaIcon").href);
```